# How to edit an XML file using Jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jstree

I'm using Jstree to display an XML file, then using it's capabilities like create and rename to edit the tree displayed, is there is a way to reflect the changes i made in the tree to the original XML file? like when i'm created a node i want that node to be created in the XML file.

**for ex.**

if the *XML file* contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu parent_id="0" >       
    <ColdDrinks>
            <pepsi  price="5" hasoption = "false"> 
            </pepsi>
            <Mango  price = "8" hasoption = "false">
            </Mango>
            <Water>
            </Water>
    </ColdDrinks>

</menu>
```

**it will be displayed like :**

[image]

**and when i add a new drink :**

[image]

**i want my XML file to be edited like that :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu parent_id="0" >       
    <ColdDrinks>
            <pepsi  price="5" hasoption = "false"> 
            </pepsi>
            <Mango  price = "8" hasoption = "false">
            </Mango>
            <Water>
            </Water>
    </ColdDrinks>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a server side language to edit files on server, like PHP. 
You can use Ajax technology to pass the changes you make in the xml content, or a string with the xml, to a php script that saves /add data in the xml file.

Comment: i can make that programatically, but where can i get the new data i added to the tree ?